# didSelectViewController

Tags: ios4

Hi I have manged to implement didSelectViewController in the app delegate but is it possible to call a method in another class. For instance I have view1 and view2, what I want to be able to do is if view2 is selected a method in that view2 class is called?

Comment: you can raise local notification in view1 and then register a method in view2 to receive notification to be called, http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your first tab contains the view controller of class `MyViewController` you can do it like this:

```
#import "MyViewController.h"

//...

- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController 
{
  if (tabBarController.selectedIndex == 0) {
    MyViewController* my = (MyViewController *)viewController;
    [my myMethod];
  }
}
```

Comment: Great thank you phix23 I got it to work. I was using **-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated** but you would have to leave the view and come back for it to fire the method. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry I have now found that if i click on the tab four times it crashes?